# Rules - Sending out Email with the custom form fields values

Tags: orchardcms

I am using Orchard 1.4.2. I had installed the Custom Form module..created a custom form which has some Enumeration fields and input fields.

Now, I want to create a rule to send out an emil when the form is submitted. The form should have the Values inserted/selected by the user.

I can get the input fields value using `Request.Form:TestForm.Firstname.Value`, but can't seem to get the Enumeration field ( Drop down) selected value. Tried various options, but nothing works.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are tokens for fields. Did you try that?

Comment: Hi Bertrand, can you please explain a bit more about how to use them? I followed this post : http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/rules-tokens-and-form-api-in-orchard-1.3     and tried both  Request.Form:TestForm.City.SelectedValue and Content.City.SelectedValue, but still the value doesn't come through..

Comment: In 1.5, you can do Content.Fields.TestForm.FirstName.Value. In 1.4.2, you may not have access to all field properties this way.

Comment: Thanks, Bertrand. Waiting for 1.5 release. Until then, is there anyway I can access the enumeration field selected value? Can easily get input field value but not the enumeration field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 1.5, you can do Content.Fields.TestForm.FirstName.Value. In 1.4.2, you may not have access to all field properties this way. In the meantime, you would have to write your own token.